# How to fix reselecting the SelectOneButton issue?

Tags: primefaces

I am developing an application using `Primefaces 6.1` and `JSF 2.2`.

In that, I am facing an issue is on `Primefaces` `selectOneButton` component, when I was clicking on an already selected `selectOneButton` value "Level 1", it's getting unselectable automatically without triggering a `model` method.

**Sample code:**

```
<p:panel id="mainPagePanelId">  // It is a main panel
<p:selectOneButton value="#{action.chooseLevelType}">
   <f:selectItem id="one" itemLabel="Level1" itemValue="0" />
   <f:selectItem id="two" itemLabel="Level2" itemValue="1" />
   <p:ajax event="change" update="mainPagePanelId" 
   listener="#{action.triggerMthd}" process="panelId"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
</p:panel>
```

**Actual:**

Here, The "Level 1" button is selected value, If I am again selecting on that same value, then it gets unselected value like a below `Bug screen shot`.

[image]

**Bug:**

[image]

This bug is not present in `Primefaces 5.1`. 
Kindly suggest me to solve this bug.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Start by looking at the releasenotes of the 6.1 and intermediate versions. Then start comparing the source of this component in 5.1 and 6.1. You might find a reason for this.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved in PrimeFaces 6.2 (assuming `unselectable="false"`).

Answer (score 5):

There is a property called `unselectable` in `p:selectOneButton` that is true by default, just change it to false

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{action.chooseLevelType}" unselectable="false">
```

Comment: But if OP **wants** unselectable, it **should** trigger the ajax listener like it does in 5.1, so it seems a regression

Comment: I am using Primefaces 6.1, in that there is no unselectable="false" with Primefaces selectOneButton component.

Comment: @venkatraj Are you sure you're using PrimeFaces 6.1? Please take a look to [PrimeFaces 6.1 Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf) page 458

Comment: @David Florez, Also in Primefaces 6.1 the same bug present.